# Editing New order email that goes to Admin in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im looking for a way to change the word "Shipping: " in the email that Admin gets after a new order was placed to something else. We are using Woo shipping to charge a Handling fee, so would like to keep it consistent and say "Handling fee" in the email as well.

Could somebody please point me to the right place?

I was able to change the wording on checkout using this:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'custom_shipping_package_name' );
function custom_shipping_package_name( $name ) {
    return 'Handling fee';
}
```

Is there a way to change it everywhere? We wont be shipping anything so it would always be Handling fee.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to functions.php file of the active theme/child theme

```
add_filter("woocommerce_get_order_item_totals", "change_shipping_label", 10, 3);
function change_shipping_label( $total_rows, $this_class, $tax_display ){
    if( isset( $total_rows["shipping"]["label"] ) ){
        $total_rows["shipping"]["label"] = "Handling Fee";
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer and voted. My vote may not show up as Im a newbie here. Have a great day, Melvin!!

Comment: Melvin, could you please let me know what 10,3 do in this function?
Thank you!

Comment: `3` means the number of arguments the function accepts. Here the function change_shipping_label accepts `3` arguments. `10` means the order in which the function associated with a filter is executed. The filter `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` can have many functions including the function we wrote. So if we want our function to execute earlier, we can use a lower number. And if we want to delay the execution, we can use a higher number. 10 is the default priority. Hope this gives you an overall idea. For more https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/